# Unable to store background color of NSTextField set via InterfaceBuilder

Tags: cocoa, colors, interface-builder, background-color, nstextfield

I am trying to cache the background color set for an `NSTextField` via the Interface Builder in a member variable for later usage in another component. At startup, the background color of the `NSTextField` is set to transparent.

```
@implementation CTTextField

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self customize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self customize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    ...
    [self customize];
}

- (void)customize {
    // Store the user defined background color.
    // FIXME: The color is not stored.
    m_userDefinedBackgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
    // Disable the background color.
    self.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:1.0f alpha:0.0f];
    ...
}

@end
```

However, `m_userDefinedBackgroundColor` is always **black**.
The whole [CocoaThemes project](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/CocoaThemes) I am working on is available at GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Your `-customize` method is called twice. When nib is loading all objects are initializing with `-initWithCoder:` and after that receives `-awakeFromNib`. You should remove your `-initWithCoder:` or `-awakeFromNib` or check `m_userDefinedBackgroundColor` for `nil` in `-customize` like this:

```
- (void)customize {
    // Store the user defined background color.
    // FIXME: The color is not stored.

    if (m_userDefinedBackgroundColor == nil)
        m_userDefinedBackgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;

    // Disable the background color.
    self.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:1.0f alpha:0.0f];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I agree with the redundant call but this does not answer my question why the background color defined via Interface Builder is not stored.

Comment: Because after first call of `-customize` you overwrite `self.backgroundColor` and the second time you set `m_userDefinedBackgroundColor` to this overwritten value and loose the original value. I've added the code to my answer.